# Access files on different user account

Tags: files, users

So, I accidentally messed up my Linux Mint 18 admin account, deleting cinnamon-settings, making it impossible to login to my user account. 
I booted up from a clean Linux Mint USB, and am probably going to wipe my SSD with all my previous data. There are several large files (in the ~/.local/share directory) which I would like to transfer to the new install. Is there a way to do this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there any reason not to just copy them?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the login command from your terminal once you've logged in as administrator? That is, your account still exists correct?

$ login user

but replace user with whatever your user account is. 
Likewise, you can exit the user account with simply

$ exit

It might be a good idea to create a new account. 
This is how I always do it: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140502074357-79939846-adding-a-new-user-in-kali-linux

Then recursively copy all your folders, sub-folders, and files to your new account.

$ sudo cp -rf ~/.local/share /path/to/your/new/account

Now try logging in as the new user you created.

Comment: Well, my admin account has been corrupted. I made a new user account, and will try copying my home folder to my new account.

Comment: How is your recursive copying procedure going?